# Why ts-node index.ts doesn't work, but ts-node through npm run works?

Tags: node.js, typescript

So I got a project for a long time now.

I decided to switch to typescript.

I installed `npm install ts-node`

When I do `ts-node src/index.ts` it tells me it doesn't know any `ts-node` command but when I run `npm run run` which looks like this:

```json
  scripts": {
    "run": "ts-node src/index.ts"
  },
```

It works fine.

After I installed `ts-node` globally it works, but is there a way to run it without installing it globally?

Comment: I think the npm checks ./node_modules/.bin folder, have a look if there's a ts-node file. So this should work `./node_modules/.bin/ts-node src/index.ts`

Comment: There is! Thanks!